# scoreboard with efficient time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

i want to maintain a scoreboard which contains n players sorted according to their scores, what i have done is :
when player i gets x points (if he is not already the top player) i compare his score with the score of the player above him to swap them if necessary, then i repeat this until i find that the player above him has score greater than his score or until he reaches the top of the list.
the problem with this that it has worst case time of O (n), can it be done in something like O (log n) ??

Comment: In practice, the worst case will never be reached, and the *one-element-bubble-sort* is the best you can do. Once the scoreboard is populated and relatively stable, typical ranking movement of an entry will change mostly be a few places. And as a bonus: the locality of reference is better than for trees or binary search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintain a [balanced search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), mapping players to score. When player *n*'s score changes by *z*,

1. find the current value of *n*, say *y*
2. Remove the entry for *n*
3. Insert a mapping from *n* to *y + z*

The complexity is logarithmic.